# вводятся числа с клавиатуры

Tags: python

Вводятся числа с клавиатуры, посчитать количество элементов не кратных 5. Причем последoвойного нажатия на enter программа должна завершиться. Вот что у меня получилось, но программа позволяет ввести только 1 элемент.

```
s = input(int())
k = int()
while s != "":
    a = int(s)
    if a % 5 != 0:
        k += 1 
print(k)
```

И как избавиться от нуля, который первым выводится?

Comment: Чтобы программа позволяла вводить числа более одного раза, нужно запрашивать их в цикле. Я вчера уже писал об этом, но вам видимо важнее спросить и получить готовенькое, чем понять.

Comment: как это написать

Answer (score 0):

Если двойным нажатием Enter считается нажатие после последнего введенного числа + нажатие после этого, то можно сделать так:

```
x = []
while True:
    a = input('-> ')
    if len(a) > 0:
        x.append(int(a))
    else:
        break

print(len([i for i in x if i % 5 != 0]))
```

===================================

```
-> 5
-> 10
-> 15
-> 13
-> 3
-> 7
-> 
3
```

Без использования списков:

```
count = 0
while True:
    a = input('-> ')
    if a:
        if int(a) % 5:
            count += 1
    else:
        break

print(count)
```

Comment: Можно так `if len(a) > 0:` -> `if a:`

Comment: а можно это реализовать без массива

Comment: @Рамзан Казанцев дополнил ответ